# systemd service unit that maximizes CPU utilization

Tags: linux, systemd, performance, cpu

How to do I write a systemd service unit that maximizes CPU utilization on a single CPU core?

What I have so far =

```
[Unit]
Description=Max_CPU_Utilization

[Service]
ExecStart=

[Install]
WantedBy=mult-user.target
```

Comment: Can you write a script or program that will use CPU as desired, then call it from `ExecStart`?

Comment: `perl -e '1 while 1'` or other such ways should spin round and round

Comment: what is perl and what does this do?

Comment: @Darren, you could easily ask a search engine "what is perl?". Please show some initiative to find answers on your own.